# What is alternative to "lock_timeout" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, session, kill, lock-timeout

I need to kill my session, if I'm blocking other sessions.But as of now we have only option to kill own session blocked by other sessions using lock_timeout.
Do we have option in postgres to timeout own session, if our session blocked other sessions not own session blocked by others?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such option.  Is the issue that you know you will hold a lock for a long time, you just don't know if anyone else will want it?  Or that you don't know how long you will hold the lock for?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` and `statement_timeout`.  Then your blocking session gets killed if it runs too long statements and if it hangs idle in a database transaction.

Answer (score 0):

[statement_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT) is alternative = [lock_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LOCK-TIMEOUT) in PostgreSQL:

> Abort any statement that takes more than the specified amount of time.

For example, `SELECT pg_sleep(30);` is timed out after 10 seconds as shown below:

```
postgres=# SET statement_timeout to 10000;
SET
postgres=# SELECT pg_sleep(30);
ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
```